meaning of tag in "with a price tag of about $25"
In the prepositional phrase:

with a price tag of about $25

Does tag meaning "a small piece of paper, plastic etc attached to something to show what it is, who owns it, what it costs etc"?
Thank you.

Please do not use textese when posting here. Not everyone knows what you mean and your abbreviations may be different in other countries.

@PeterJennings OK, I see. I will pay attention to next time. The meaning of "tag" that I paste in question is from dictionary.

Yes, but it may be being used non-literally.  We can talk about the "price tag" to mean "the indicated price" of an item which doesn't have physical tags.

The price tag on this computer is $700, but the store is having a sale so I can get it for less.

While "tags" were a common way to indicate price in the past, and are still used in clothing shops, many shops don't use tags any more. And of course in e-commerce there won't be a physical tag.  But you could still talk about the "price tag" in a non-literal way.

Thank you for your explanation. I see.

It's worth noting that in AmE the phrase "sticker price" is similar and is used in car sales (and similar) where there is frequently a large sticker on the windscreen showing the price of the vehicle. I doesn't seem to have caught on much this side of the pond.

@PeterJennings - A lot of UK car dealers make up the price using separate stick-on digits which are read to show what is often called the 'windscreen price' : 47% of dealers say they build a small “haggle margin” into the windscreen price of their used cars

@MichaelHarvey Agreed. I didn't make myself clear. What I meant was calling the windscreen price "the sticker price" in the UK has not caught on, not the practice of posting the price in large numbers on the windscreen itself. That's common practice everywhere.

@PeterJennings - a quick Google Image search (not scientific, I know) seems to show lots of US used cars with a single sticker that has been made-up, often red, with comtrasting digits, while many UK ones have separate digits.

@PeterJennings  The large sticker showing the MSRP is usually on a side window  in the US :-)   Used car lots often put the price in giant numbers with some kind of washable paint on the windshield so it can be seen and read by passing motorists.   Maybe the paint scrapes off. Not sure that it is washable.  But the invididual digits of the price are about a foot tall.

And the use of sticker price that @PeterJennings mentions also gave us the term sticker shock, which means “surprise, horror, or concern caused by learning the price of some good or service.”
